# Android XML file doesn't save

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I'm writing a game with LibGDX, and I'm trying to save an XML file, but there's always an exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/Slugfest/teams/Team1.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)) when saving the file. This code saves the file.

```
public void save() {
    try {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result;

        if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android) {
            result = new StreamResult(new File("/data/Slugfest/teams/" + name + ".xml"));
        } else {
            result = new StreamResult(new File(name + ".xml"));
        }
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        Gdx.app.log("Slugfest", "File saved.");
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        Gdx.app.log("Slugfest", tfe.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

My manifest file includes the WRITE/READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions, by the way.

Comment: I don;t know about `LibGDX` but in case of simple android you need to make a dir if it is not available. Like `File dir = new File ("path to file");` and then 



    if(dir.exists()==false) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
               }

and then for file

    File file = new File(dir, fileName);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the directory you are trying to save to. You should check to see if it is there, if not, the create it. Something like this:

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() == null) {
                directory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                        + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
                photoDirectory = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory()
                        + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
                /*
                 * this checks to see if there are any previous test photo files
                 * if there are any photos, they are deleted for the sake of
                 * memory
                 */
                if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                    File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                    if (dirFiles.length != 0) {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii <= dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                            dirFiles[ii].delete();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if no directory exists, create new directory
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdir();
                }

                // if phone DOES have sd card
            } else if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != null) {
                // search for directory on SD card
                directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/RobotiumTestLog/");
                photoDirectory = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/Robotium-Screenshots/");
                if (photoDirectory.exists()) {
                    File[] dirFiles = photoDirectory.listFiles();
                    if (dirFiles.length > 0) {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < dirFiles.length; ii++) {
                            dirFiles[ii].delete();
                        }
                        dirFiles = null;
                    }
                }
                // if no directory exists, create new directory to store test
                // results
                if (!directory.exists()) {
                    directory.mkdir();
                }
            }
```

Here I check to see if there is an SD card, if not, the I save locally, otherwise, I save to the SD. I also check for files, and delete if they are there. You might not need that, but this is a comprehensive algorithm that should do what you need it to. Take what you need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad I could help! Feel free to accept and upvote if you like :)